# unable to deploy to IBM websphere application server using ant

Tags: websphere-8

I am using ant to deploy an ear file to WAS. I am successfully able to generate the ear and then using the following to deploy to localhost

```
<target name="deploy" depends="buildEar">
        <echo message="${toString:was.runtime}"/>
        <taskdef name="wsInstallApp" classpath="${was_cp}" classname="com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.InstallApplication" />
        <wsInstallApp wasHome="${WAS.home}" ear="${earFile}" failonerror="true" />
    </target>
```

This is what was_cp looks like

```
<property name="was_home" value="C:/ibm/WebSphere855/AppServer">
    </property>
    <path id="was.runtime">
        <fileset dir="${was_home}/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${was_home}/plugins">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <property name="user.install.root" value="${was_home}/profiles/AppSrv01" />
    <property name="was_cp" value="${toString:was.runtime}" />
    <property name="java.endorsed.dirs" value="${toString:was.runtime}" />
```

I get the following error. Thanks for your help!

```
[wsInstallApp] Installing Application [K:\uoc-dev\bceEAR\build\ear\bce.ear]...
  [wsadmin] WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node zinfandelNode01 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
  [wsadmin] WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "C:\Users\IBM_AD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wsant8484530159820548868jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed]
  [wsadmin] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by using the ws_ant.bat file to run the build instead of using default ant on my machine.